# Disable Activex Option Button with previous Activex Option Button (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to disable a question set, with a "No" answer from the previous question. I am using all ActiveX Option Buttons in the worksheet.

The user will be asked a yes / no question. If no is selected, I want to disable the next question. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1()
   If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        OptionButton3.Enabled = True
        OptionButton4.Enabled = True
    Else
        OptionButton3.Enabled = False
        OptionButton4.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It is not working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tryed to use event "Change"?

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
   If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        OptionButton3.Enabled = True
        OptionButton4.Enabled = True
    Else
        OptionButton3.Enabled = False
        OptionButton4.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So the code will be called on every change of the first option button

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I had a time pressure and have given up on the idea. Thank you for the input and help.

Comment: @JonathanH What does it mean "it did not work" . What happens?